# MySQL Min value query group by second column not getting the proper value of third column

Tags: php, mysql

My table Structure is like below

vendor_id     account_id     price         code

27                 2                    0.058         91

29                 2                    0.065         91

23                 2                    0.043         91

30                 2                    0.085         91

31                 3                    0.085         91

I have to get the the minimum price where code should be equal to 91, price between given range and group by account_id

I am using the select query as

**select MIN(price) as min_price, account_id, vendor_id from tbl_input_values where code='91' and price>=0 and price<=2 group by account_id**

And i am getting the output as

min_price     account_id     vendor_id

0.043                    2                    27

0.085                    3                    31

But it should be

min_price     account_id     vendor_id

0.043                    2                    23

0.085                    3                    31

Comment: `full_code`  or `code` ?

Comment: Amir its code, in the query by mistake written as full_code

Answer (score 0):

Try this query -

```
SELECT
  t1.*
FROM tbl_input_values t1
JOIN (
  SELECT
    MIN(price) AS min_price,
    account_id
  FROM tbl_input_values
  WHERE code = '91' AND price >= 0 AND price <= 2
  GROUP BY account_id
  ) t2
    ON t1.account_id = t2.account_id AND t1.price = t2.min_price
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this query

```
 SELECT 
      price, 
      account_id, 
      vendor_id 
 from 
      Table1
 where 
      (vendor_id, price) in 
      (select 
            vendor_id, 
            min(price) 
       from 
            Table1 
       WHERE 
            code = '91' AND 
            price >= 0 AND 
            price <= 2
       group by 
            account_id)
```

Without subquery using join

```
  SELECT 
        a.price, 
        a.account_id, 
        a.vendor_id 
  from 
        Table1 a,
        (select 
               vendor_id, 
               min(price) as 'price' 
        from 
               Table1 
        where 
               code='91' and 
               price>=0 and 
               price<=2
        group by 
               account_id) b
  WHERE 
        a.vendor_id = b.vendor_id AND 
        a.price = b.price
```

Answer (score 0):

Your query is correctly selecting the minimum price per account_id, but it's necessary to correlate this price with the vendor_id.

Here's my version :

```
SELECT iv.price AS min_price, iv.account_id, iv.vendor_id
  FROM tbl_input_values AS iv
  INNER JOIN (select min(price) AS min_price, account_id
    FROM tbl_input_values
    WHERE full_code='91' AND price>=0 AND price<=2
    GROUP BY account_id) AS mp
 ON iv.price=mp.min_price AND iv.account_id=mp.account_id;
```

If two vendors have the same minimum price for an account_id, this query returns both.

See the SQL fiddle here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/96d24/8

Answer (score 0):

try;

```
SELECT tData.price, tData.account_id, tData.vendor_id FROM tbl_input_values, (SELECT price, account_id, vendor_id FROM tbl_input_values ORDER BY price ASC) AS tData WHERE tbl_input_values.account_id = tData.account_id GROUP by tbl_input_values.account_id;
```